# Send a UDP datagram to myself using public IP address

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, udp

Is it possible to send a UDP datagram to myself using my public IP address? I'm trying to send a datagram using the following C++/Qt code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QNetworkDatagram>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QHostAddress addr("my public IP address");

    QUdpSocket sock2;
    sock2.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 49152);

    QUdpSocket sock1;

    sock1.bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 49150);
    sock1.connectToHost(addr, 49152);
    qDebug() << sock1.errorString();
    sock1.writeDatagram("test",4,addr,49152);
    qDebug() << sock2.receiveDatagram().data();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But get error "Network unreachable". But if I use 127.0.0.1 as addr instead of public IP address, then everything works

Comment: Try to bind soket2 to QHostAddress::Any

Comment: @tunglt Thanks, the error is gone, however, instead of data, I get an empty string when I call sock2.receiveDatagram().data()

Comment: You should use readyRead signal to handle incomming datagram

Comment: @tunglt i am already use readyRead signal, but no data received

Comment: So take out wireshark or tcpdump to see where your packet goes ? firewall ? route ? etc.

Comment: @tunglt Wireshark shows that the packet is being transmitted over the wireless LAN to the specified public IP address

Comment: You are trying to do hairpin routing, but not all routers support that, and it is a poor way to do things as it wastes router resources and LAN band width. The proper way to do it is to use split DNS so that local traffic remains local.

Comment: @RonMaupin How can I check if this feature is supported by my router?

Comment: This is the wrong SE site. You could try to ask that on [su].